# How to create Opportunity in SAP CRM?

Tags: abap, sap-crm

I am Java developer and I am pretty new to SAP CRM, but the requirement in current project requires me to have a basic understanding of the SAP CRM system. I want to know on which Tool I can find the Accounts, Opportunity, Leads etc in SAP. If the question is not complete please ask me appropriate question, I will try to explain to the best of my knowledge.

I have already gone through multiple videos and tutorials but to no help, code is not available at the moment

I expect somebody to let me know where exactly I can find the above fields (Accounts, Opportunity, Cases, etc like in Salesforce) in SAP CRM.

Comment: You need to create opportunity programmatically or manually for testing?

Comment: programmaticaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BAPI_OPPORTUNITY_CREATEMULTI` for that, and don't  forget to run commit after the BAPI, otherwise your opportunity will not appear in tables. Here is the sample:

```
DATA: return            TYPE TABLE OF BAPIRET2 WITH HEADER LINE,
      it_opportunity    TYPE BAPIBUS20001_OPPORTUNITY,
      it_header         TYPE BAPIBUS20001_HEADER_INS,
      it_item           TYPE BAPIBUS20001_ITEM,
      it_input_fields   TYPE BAPIBUS20001_INPUT_FIELDS,
      it_pricing        TYPE BAPIBUS20001_PRICING,
      <fs_partner>      TYPE BAPIBUS20001_PARTNER_INS,
      w_status          TYPE BAPIBUS20001_STATUS_INS.

* gc_handle_1 is used for an item to bind it to a opportunity and gc_handle_2 is used to bind the information for an item to an item.
CONSTANTS: gc_handle_1 TYPE crmt_handle VALUE '0000000001',
           gc_handle_2 TYPE crmt_handle VALUE '0000000002'.

* --ITEM DATA--

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_item ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_item>).
<fs_item>-mode = 'A'.
<fs_item>-ordered_prod = int_tab-produkt. "your product
<fs_item>-itm_type = 'ZOPT'.
<fs_item>-handle = gc_handle_2. "Identification of this item
<fs_item>-header_handle = gc_handle_1. "Refers to the opportunity for which this item is for.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_fields>).
<fs_fields>-ref_handle = gc_handle_2. "Refers to the item for which this information is for 
<fs_fields>-objectname = 'ORDERADM_I'.
<fs_fields>-ref_kind = 'B'.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'ORDERED_PROD'.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'ITM_TYPE'.

CLEAR return.

* --HEADER DATA --

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_header ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_header>).
<fs_header>-guid = ''.
<fs_header>-handle = gc_handle_1. "Identification of this opportunity
CONCATENATE 'Konv: ' int_tab-betegnelse INTO <fs_header>-description SEPARATED BY space.
<fs_header>-process_type = 'ZOPP'.
<fs_header>-descr_language = 'K'.
<fs_header>-langu_iso = 'DA'.
<fs_header>-posting_date = sy-datum.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-ref_handle = gc_handle_1.
<fs_fields>-objectname = 'ORDERADM_H'.
<fs_fields>-ref_kind = 'A'.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'PROCESS_TYPE'.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'OBJECT_ID'.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'DESCRIPTION'.

* --PARTNER DATA--

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO <fs_partner> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_partner>).
<fs_partner>-ref_handle = gc_handle_1.
<fs_partner>-display_type = 'BP'.
<fs_partner>-no_type = 'BP'.
<fs_partner>-ref_kind = 'A'.
<fs_partner>-ref_partner_handle = '0000'.
<fs_partner>-partner_no = int_tab-kundeemne.
<fs_partner>-partner_fct = '00000021'.
<fs_partner>-mainpartner = 'X'.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO <fs_partner> ASSIGNING <fs_partner>.
<fs_partner>-mainpartner = ''.
<fs_partner>-partner_no = int_tab-kontpers.
<fs_partner>-partner_fct = '00000015'.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO <fs_partner> ASSIGNING <fs_partner>.
<fs_partner>-partner_no = int_tab-amedarb.
<fs_partner>-partner_fct = 'Z0000014'.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-objectname = 'PARTNER'.
<fs_fields>-logical_key = '0000'.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'PARTNER_FCT'.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'PARTNER_NO'.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'DISPLAY_TYPE'.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'NO_TYPE'.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'KIND_OF_ENTRY'.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'MAINPARTNER'.

* --OPPORTUNITY DATA--

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_opportunity ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_opportunity>).
<fs_opportunity>-ref_handle = gc_handle_1.
<fs_opportunity>-startdate = int_tab-start.
<fs_opportunity>-expect_end = int_tab-****.
<fs_opportunity>-probability = int_tab-succes.
<fs_opportunity>-curr_phase = int_tab-aktfas.
<fs_opportunity>-forecast_rel = int_tab-relpro.
<fs_opportunity>-type = int_tab-smgrp.
<fs_opportunity>-importance = int_tab-priori.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-objectname = 'OPPORT_H'.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'STARTDATE'.

* --PRICING DATA-
READ TABLE it_opportunity ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_opp>) INDEX 1.

*-- Needed to store CURRENCY.
CLEAR it_pricing.
APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_it_pricing ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_pricing>).
<fs_pricing>-REF_HANDLE = 1.
<fs_pricing>-REF_GUID = g_BlankGuid.
<fs_pricing>-REF_KIND = 'A'.
<fs_pricing>-CURRENCY = <fs_opp>-CURRENCY.
<fs_pricing>-CURRENCY_ISO = <fs_opp>-CURRENCY_ISO.

* --OPPORTUNITY DATA--

CLEAR w_status.
w_status-ref_guid = l_opportunity_guid.
w_status-ref_handle = l_count_ref_handle.
w_status-ref_kind = 'A'.
w_status-status = 'E0001'.
w_status-user_stat_proc = 'ZOPPRSTU'.
w_status-activate = 'X'.
APPEND w_status TO t_status.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-ref_handle = l_count_ref_handle.
<fs_fields>-ref_guid = l_opportunity_guid.
<fs_fields>-ref_kind = 'A'.
<fs_fields>-objectname = 'STATUS'.
CONCATENATE w_status-status w_status-user_stat_proc INTO <fs_fields>-logical_key.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'STATUS'.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'USER_STAT_PROC'.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO it_input_fields ASSIGNING <fs_fields>.
<fs_fields>-fieldname = 'ACTIVATE'.

CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_OPPORTUNITY_CREATEMULTI'
  EXPORTING
    TESTRUN = ' '
  TABLES
    HEADER = it_header
    OPPORTUNITY = it_opportunity
    PARTNER = it_partner
    PRICING = it_pricing
    INPUT_FIELDS = it_input_fields
    RETURN = return
    ITEM = it_item
    STATUS = w_status.

* Opportunity will not appear until you commit.

CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'
  EXPORTING
   WAIT = abap_true.
```

Also check report `CRM_REPORT_CREATE_MASS_OPPT`.

Using the tcode `/ncrmd_BUS2000111` you can create opportunity in GUI mode.

What concerns

> where exactly I can find the above fields(Accounts, Opportunity, Cases, etc like in Salesforce) in SAP CRM

they are all stored in CRM tables, presumably `CRMD_ORDERADM_H` and `CRMD_ORDERADM_I` and all business objects manipulations in CRM are made via WebUI. If you have appropriate [business role](http://sapuniversity.eu/the-sap-crm-business-role/) (e.g. `SALESPRO`) you will find opportunity [in the navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ5nz.png) at the left.

Comment: Thnx.. that helped alot.